# PopUp LOV with Multi-Select

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Oracle APEX gives us the option of creating a POP-UP LOV, but I couldn't find any way to have multiple select in this item.

Is there any way to have multiple select in POP-UP LOVs?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Item

```
Type : Popup LOV
Multiple values : Yes
List of value: SQL query

select ename, empno from emp
```

Comment: This feature is not available in Oracle 5.1.

Comment: You can try this plugin https://github.com/Pretius/Pretius-APEX-Enhanced-Lov-Item

Comment: Consider upgrade if you can, there are a lot of cool new features in the subsequent releases.

Answer (score 0):

Apex doesn't offer it, so I'd say *not*. Maybe with some help of e.g. JavaScript or something else, I can't tell.

Select list items or shuttles let you select more values, if you want to use them instead.

Comment: actually the Popup Lov was completely rewritten in release 19.2 and now multi-select is just an option.

Comment: I see, @Koen; I'm still on 18.2 (and didn't check apex.oracle.com).